# Use seconds from mysql to jquery setInterval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, setinterval

I have a slideshow and every slides have its seconds stored in my database to play the slideshow.

**Is it possible to use a variable as timer for setInterval function?**

Written like this I get the error: **too much recursion**

Here's my jquery + php code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

<?php

    $sqlSlides = "SELECT *
                  FROM slides
                  WHERE start <= NOW() 
                  And end >= NOW()";

        $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlSlides);


        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $timer = $row["timer"];
        }
?>

        var timeshow = '<?php $timer;?>';

          $(function(){


            $ds = $('.boxslideshow .wrap');
            $ds.hide().eq(0).show();

            setInterval(function(){

                $ds.filter(':visible').fadeOut(function(){

                    var $div = $(this).next('.wrap');

                    if ($div.length == 0) {
                        $ds.eq(0).fadeIn(1000);
                    } else {
                        $div.fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                });
            }, timeshow);
          }); 

 });
```

Comment: For starters, replace `<?php $timer;?>` with `<?php echo $timer;?>`, otherwise your `timeshow` variable will just be an empty string.

Comment: all sorts of problems ...overwriting same variable in each iteration of `while` loop, no output to timshow value in script tag , no logic in slide show to use different times even if you did have an array in `timeshow`

Comment: The thing is that I have to show all my slides with its time from database, so how would you do it please?